# Oauth 1.0 with Play framework - get instead of post

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework-2.0

I'm implementing access to OAuth service in Play 2.0 application. Generally I'm doing this like described here: 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaOAuth

Unfortunately the service I'm accessing rejects POST request - which Play sends. Can I change Play's behavior to do GET requests undercover?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to write a custom method to handle GET as Play's OAuth object defers request handling to the Commons HTTP library.

Here's a link to the source code for OAuth.scala.  Using Play's WS library it should be straightforward to pattern your custom HTTP call based on this:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/0c265c943a801b2cc9b65e055c956a125f072a64/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/oauth/OAuth.scala